# How to use PyInstaller in a compiled Python file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python program that needs to create other exectuables, I'll call it `main.py`.
When I run `main.py` normally it creates the other executables just  fine, but when I compile `main.py` using PyInstaller and then run it, it stops after creating the dist and build folders.

I've tried these methods of creating exectuables inside `main.py`:

```
PyInstaller.__main__.run([spec_file_path])
--------
subprocess.Popen([path_to_pyinstaller, spec_file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
--------
subprocess.call(r"python -m PyInstaller main.spec")
```

I've also tried using normal python files instead of `.spec` files.

Is it possible to fix this problem?